# Probability - Find the CDF of Z=Y-X

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Hi everyone :) I'm trying to find my mistake in the following question:
Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over $[a,b]$ and Y exponentially distributed with a $\lambda$ parameter. Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, find the CDF of $Z=Y-X$.

My answer:
$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(Y-X\leq z)=P(Y\leq X+z)$. Let's look at the following boundaries:

for $z>-a$:
[graph a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPnI8.png)

So the calculation is:
$$F_Z(z)=\int\limits _{a}^{b}\int\limits _{0}^{x+z}\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{b-a}dtds=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(b+\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda\left(z+b\right)}-a-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda\left(z+a\right)}\right)$$

For $-b<z\leq -a$: [graph b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yJ5o.png)

So the calculation is:
$$F_Z(z)=\int\limits _{z}^{b}\int\limits _{0}^{x+z}\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{b-a}dtds=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(b+\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda\left(z+b\right)}-z-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-2\lambda z}\right)$$

For $z\leq -b$: [graph c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bHO6.png)

So $F_Z(z)=0$

According to my class mates the $z>-a$ case is correct but the $-b<z\leq -a$ is wrong.

I'll be grateful if anyone could help me find my mistake :)
Thank you!!!

Comment: It's a bit odd to use $x$ in the limits for the integral with respect to $x$. One would expect the $x$ from the limits to appear again somewhere in the end result of the integral.

Comment: Correct, didn't notice it. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first case is indeed correct.

$$\begin{align*}F_Z(z)&=\int_{x=a}^{x=b}\int_{y=0}^{y=x+z}\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda y}}{b-a}\,dy\,dx\\&=-\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\left(e^{-\lambda(x+z)}-1\right)\,dx\\&=\frac1{b-a}\left(b-a+\frac{e^{-\lambda(b+z)}-e^{-\lambda(a+z)}}\lambda\right)\\&=1+\frac{e^{-\lambda(b+z)}-e^{-\lambda(a+z)}}{\lambda(b-a)}\end{align*}$$

---

Your second case integral contains a small error.

The only change is to the lower limit with respect to $x$. Now $x$ varies from where the line $y=x+z$ meets the $x$-axis $(y=0\implies x=-z)$, up to previous upper limit $x=b$. You should thus have

$$\begin{align*}F_Z(z)&=\int_{x=\color{red}{-z}}^{x=b}\int_{y=0}^{y=x+z}\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda y}}{b-a}\,dy\,dx\\&=-\frac1{b-a}\int_{-z}^{b}\left(e^{-\lambda(x+z)}-1\right)\,dx\\&=\frac{\color{red}{z}+b}{b-a} + \frac{e^{-\lambda(b+z)}\color{red}{-1}}{\lambda(b-a)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Amazing how advanced calculus makes me forget basic 7th grade's math. Thank you!!